# Android - SensorEventListenr in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am trying to add a sensoreventlistener to a fragment in my app.

Below is the code I am using to define the Sensor

```
Context context;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.game, container, false);
        this.context = context;

         mSensorManager = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
//above is line 49 which is referenced in the logcat
         mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

//...
return mLinearLayout;
}
```

And here is the logcat error

```
07-27 00:19:50.907: E/AndroidRuntime(20595): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 00:19:50.907: E/AndroidRuntime(20595): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 00:19:50.907: E/AndroidRuntime(20595):    at com.Optimus.iwould.Game.onCreateView(Game.java:49)
07-27 00:19:50.907: E/AndroidRuntime(20595):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
07-27 00:19:50.907: E/AndroidRuntime(20595):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your context is `null`

```
this.context = context;
```

and your are using context at line 49

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

**which is null**

Comment: so how do I make it not null

Comment: @CamConnor either try by  getActivity() or by this keyword !

Comment: My apologies, didnt realize.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```